# Edit compose key - in system/preferences/keyboard

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, unicode, unicode-entry, compose-key

I am trying to allow for a compose key - I would like to type in unicode characters with one keystroke (that is my end goal here).

I got here (see picture):

[image]

But I cannot seem to enable it. Anyone know how I can enable the compose key, so that I can type unicode characters. On MacOS, I can type alt+j and I get ∆, that's the kind of functionality I am looking for.

Comment: Please do not waste your bounty and reward one answer

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Compose</kbd> key behaves a bit differently than you expect. It is not a modifier like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> which should remain pressed while you typing the rest character(s). <kbd>Compose</kbd> is pressed, then released and the keyboard switches to the state which waits for the additional key sequence. If the key sequence is valid, it is transformed into some Unicode symbol, if it is invalid, keyboard leaves this state and waits for the next keystrokes. For example, to enter [Em-dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash) symbol (long dash) I should press <kbd>Compose</kbd>, <kbd>-</kbd>, <kbd>-</kbd>, <kbd>-</kbd> sequentially.
Valid sequences can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose_key).
And one more source: `/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose` (this one is *huge*).

In order to set <kbd>Compose</kbd> key, press **Disabled** word to the right of **Compose** in the window you provided in your question. Then press the button which will take over Compose function. For example, I use <kbd>Menu</kbd> button, which isn't used too often. It is located between right <kbd>Super</kbd> (with window logo) and right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>. Close the window and try some Compose combination in any editor.

Answer (score 2):

I invite you to enable <kbd>Compose</kbd> key to use standard sequences, where greek letters are available behind a `<dead_greek>` key you have to map on your keyboard with `xmodmap`. For this option, please refer to details at https://superuser.com/a/1229239/115238

To create sequences for your own need, you also can follow [these instructions](https://charlieharvey.org.uk/page/type_lambda_charcter_with_compose_on_xwindows_on_debian) . For greek letter in mathematics context, you may also simply reuse proposals you can found [here](https://newton.cx/~peter/2013/04/typing-greek-letters-easily-on-linux/).

To sum up, but please read previous references for details:

First, enforce `xim` input method thanks to `export GTK_IM_MODULE=xim` in `/etc/environment`

Second, create your own `.XCompose` file in your `$HOME` folder, including your current language keyboard mapping compose sequences:

```
include "%L"
<Multi_key> <period> <backslash>       : "λ"   U03BB  # GREEK SMALL LETTER LAMBDA
<Multi_key> <slash> <backslash>        : "Λ"   U039B  # GREEK CAPITAL LETTER LAMBDA
<Multi_key> <asciicircum> <underscore> : "Δ"   U0394  # GREEK CAPITAL LETTER DELTA
```

To get effects, you have to restart your desktop environment. For information, `%L` refers to your current keyboard mapping `/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose`.

<kbd>Compose</kbd> key behavior is configured with graphical symbols addition in mind, for instance, <kbd>Compose</kbd> <kbd>Y</kbd> <kbd>=</kbd> produces `¥`

That is why I proposed <kbd>Compose</kbd> <kbd>^</kbd> <kbd>_</kbd> to produce `Δ` instead of latin letter equivalent `D` prefixed by `g` like you may find at https://gist.github.com/pkgw/5422749

Remark: WinCompose tool allows to get same intuitive behavior on Windows system.

Comment: One note: "Δ" is Greek capital Delta, capital Lambda is "Λ". Aside from that, your answer has got valuable info regarding `~/.XCompose` and custom combinations for Compose key.

Comment: Thanks for reporting such a mistake. I have not done maths or physics since decades...